# laravel - How can i use same url in 2 route group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-filters

Suppose I have 2 filters

1) Admin
2) SuperAdmin

Filters:

```
 Route::filter('Admin', function($route, $request)
 {
   if ( ! Auth::user()->Admin()) {
   return Response::json(array('flash' => 'You are not authorized.'), 401);
 }
});

Route::filter('SuperAdmin', function($route, $request)
{
  if ( ! Auth::user()->SuperAdmin()) {
  return Response::json(array('flash' => 'You are not authorized.'), 401);
}
});
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(array('before' => array('auth|Admin')), function()
{

    Route::get('/report/{id}','ReportCntrl@getreport');
    Route::get('/create1','ReportCntrl@create1');

}


Route::group(array('before' => array('auth|SuperAdmin')), function()
{

    Route::get('/report/{id}','ReportCntrl@getreport');
    Route::get('/create2','ReportCntrl@create2');
    Route::get('/create3','ReportCntrl@create3');

}
```

so the problem is when I login from `superadmin` it says unauthorized access

because I think it passes my request to both filters and one approves it and second disapproves it.

Is there any way that i can actually use to access same url from 2 route groups in Laravel.

Comment: why dont you try validating `Admin` in `SuperAdmin` filter itself

Comment: show us code for both filters, I suggest make one and do something like `if is_admin or is_superadmin return true;`

Comment: try custom filters [Laravel Filters](http://culttt.com/2013/09/16/use-laravel-4-filters/)

Comment: because `superadmin` have some rights which should not be accessible for admin.

Comment: @Kyslik updated the question please suggest

Comment: You could build a custom filter as advised above or alternatively you could just change the view depending on the permissions so it will route the same just the view they get as an admin will be slightly less options. you could use blade template or alternatively you could just return 2 different views from the controller 1 for admin and 1 for super admin

Comment: Or you can try just reversing the order (do not really know if this works but worth a try) put route using superadmin filter higher up in code

Comment: @Kyslik see have added some other routes too please check and suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use one single filter. But you can make use of filter parameters to make it dynamic and reusable.

```
Route::filter('role', function($route, $request, $value){
    $allowedRoles = explode(';', $value);
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(in_array('Admin', $alloweRoles) && $user->Admin()){
        return;
    }
    else if(in_array('SuperAdmin', $allowedRoles) && $user->SuperAdmin()){
        return;
    }
    return Response::json(array('flash' => 'You are not authorized.'), 401);
});
```

And you use it like this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => array('auth|role:Admin;SuperAdmin')), function(){
    Route::get('/report/{id}','ReportCntrl@getreport');
}
```

#### Explanation

The three filter parameters (`$route, $request, $value`) are automatically passed in that order by Laravel. The third parameter `$value` contains everything passed after `:`. [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters)

`$request` is the current request object (instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`) and `$route` the current route object (instance of `lluminate\Routing\Route`)

Comment: this one is awesome!!

Comment: hey can u please xplain me exactly what i will get in this 3 variables

$route =??
$request =?
$value=??

Comment: @AngularDev See http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing section "Specifying Filter Parameters".

Comment: if i am not wrong it is not properly documented there they are not showing what i am getting in those vars

Comment: Request object? and route object? that means

1) URL frm where filter has got the request
2) Name of controller where it is suppose to hit.

am i right??

Comment: @AngularDev see the last line. do you want know more?

Comment: yes @lukasgeiter if possible i want to know more about $request & $route i mean if you just confirm if what i have commented above is right or wrong will be very helpful 4 me to understand.

Comment: @AngularDev Not exactly. They are instances of the request and route class. I updated the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Route::filter('AdminAndSuperAdmin', function($route, $request)
 {
   if ( ! Auth::user()->Admin() && ! Auth::user()->SuperAdmin()) {
   return Response::json(array('flash' => 'You are not authorized.'), 401);
 }
});



// this route will work for both admin and super admin
Route::group(array('before' => array('auth|AdminAndSuperAdmin')), function()
{

    Route::get('/report/{id}','ReportCntrl@getreport');

} 


Route::group(array('before' => array('auth|Admin')), function()
{

    Route::get('/create1','ReportCntrl@create1');

}


Route::group(array('before' => array('auth|SuperAdmin')), function()
{

    Route::get('/create2','ReportCntrl@create2');
    Route::get('/create3','ReportCntrl@create3');

}
```

Comment: see my updated question i have added some other routes too. pls check and suggest

Comment: Basically i will have to make one group for common url also.. r u sure there is no different way because have mentioned here only 2 roles there are more roles in my app and many of them are sharing many common urls

Comment: @AngularDev check lukasgeiter's answer below, it's more dynamic and works for any number of rules.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping Laravel routes can be confusing due to the order of definition. The filters are defined **before** the routes, but during routing the routes are first matched and only then the filters are applied.

What you are trying to achieve would only work if falsy filters (say SuperAdmin == false) would make Laravel ignore the route.

I would suggest making `Auth::user()->Admin()` also evaluate to `true` for super admins. In that way equal routes will still work, but all routes that are different (between the groups) will work properly.

Comment: example pls? 
because if i did that admin will be able to access the routes of superadmin

Comment: @AngularDev Am I correct to assume that the routes will have the same endpoint? That `/report/{id}` will go to `ReportCntrl@getreport` regardless of Admin or SuperAdmin?

Comment: yaa but if i have route `/create2` & `/create3` exclusively for superadmin then what will happen?

Comment: @AngularDev Than it will still work, because those routes are matched and the SuperAdmin filter is applied. Your problem lies in duplicate routes and the fact that the Admin filters returns a 401 response - instead of checking of other defined routes DO match.